# Java JAX-RS web service: adding nodes to JAXB XML result as threads complete

Tags: java, xml, ajax, web-services, http

I have programmed a JAX-RS web service with Jersey that queries prices from different websites and gives the result back as XML through JAXB annotated classes. Unfortunately some websites take up to 15 seconds to respond so I am using multiple threads to inquire those prices.

I would like to write a client to this webservice now and my web users will not want to wait for 30 seconds after they hit 'search' for the result to come so my idea is dynamically updating the result table as the results from my JAX-RS webservice come back.

After 30 seconds my webservice should time out and close the `<result>`-Element or after all threads completed.

**Right now my webservice runs all threads and gives back the result after all trheads are completed, I would like to dynamically add results to the XML output as they come, how can I accomplish that?**

The structure of the XML response is:

```
<result>
  <articles>
    <article>
    content of article
    </article>
  </articles>
  As the webservice gets results from websites it adds new articles to the XML
</result>
```

---

### RequestController.java

```
@Path("/request")
public class RequestController {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public Response getRequest(@QueryParam("part") String part) {
        response = new Response();
        driverController = new DriverController(this.response, this.part);
        this.response = driverController.query();
        return this.response;
    }
}
```

### DriverController.java

```
public class DriverController {


    public Response query() {
        CompletionService<Deque<Article>> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<Deque<Article>>(
                Worker.getThreadPool());
        final Deque<Article> articleQueue = new LinkedList<Article>();

        int submittedTasks = 0;

        // This threadwill take about 4 seconds to finish
        Driver driverA = new DriverA(this.part,
                this.currency, this.language);

        // This thread will take about 15 seconds to finish
        Driver driverN = new DriverN(this.part,
                this.currency, this.language);

        completionService.submit(driverA);
        submittedTasks++;
        completionService.submit(driverN);
        submittedTasks++;

        for (int i = 0; i < submittedTasks; i++) {
            log.info("Tasks: " + submittedTasks);
            try {
                Future<Deque<Article>> completedFuture = completionService.take();
                try {
                    Deque<Article> articleQueueFromThread = completedFuture.get();
                    if (articleQueueFromThread != null) {
                        articleQueue.addAll(articleQueueFromThread);
                        response.setStatus("OK");
                    }
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    log.error(e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        for (Article article : articleQueue) {
            this.response.addArticle(article);
        }
        return this.response;
    }
}
```

### Response.java

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Response {

    Queue<Article> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Article>();
    private String status;
    private String code;
    private String message;
    private List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<Article>();

    public Response(){

    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void addArticle(Article article) {
        this.articles.add(article);
        System.out.println("Response: ADDED ARTICLE TO RESPONSE");
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "article")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "articles")
    public List<Article> getArticles() {
        return articles;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started to adapt your code to do it, but I decided it was easier to work up an independent example. The example starts a Grizzly+Jersey server with a single resource class in it. A GET on the resource spawns three threads that delay for 2, 4, and 6 seconds before returning some objects. After the server starts, another thread makes a request to the server. When you run it, you can plainly see that the requester receives chunks of XML as the respective threads finish their work in the server. The one thing it doesn't do is wrap separately-delivered XML chunks in a single root element since that should be relatively trivial.

The entire executable source is below, and if you have maven and git, you can clone it from github and run it with:

```
git clone git://github.com/zzantozz/testbed.git tmp
cd tmp
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=rds.jersey.JaxRsResource -pl jersey-with-streaming-xml-response
```

Source:

```
import com.sun.grizzly.http.SelectorThread;
import com.sun.jersey.api.container.grizzly.GrizzlyWebContainerFactory;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

@Path("/streaming")
public class JaxRsResource {
    private static ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    private static int fooCounter;
    private Marshaller marshaller;

    public JaxRsResource() throws JAXBException {
        marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class).createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.fragment", Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public StreamingOutput streamStuff() {
        System.out.println("Got request for streaming resource; starting delayed response threads");
        final List<Future<List<Foo>>> futureFoos = new ArrayList<Future<List<Foo>>>();
        futureFoos.add(executorService.submit(new DelayedFoos(2)));
        futureFoos.add(executorService.submit(new DelayedFoos(4)));
        futureFoos.add(executorService.submit(new DelayedFoos(6)));
        return new StreamingOutput() {
            public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException {
                for (Future<List<Foo>> futureFoo : futureFoos) {
                    writePartialOutput(futureFoo, output);
                    output.write("\n".getBytes());
                    output.flush();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void writePartialOutput(Future<List<Foo>> futureFoo, OutputStream output) {
        try {
            List<Foo> foos = futureFoo.get();
            System.out.println("Server sending a chunk of XML");
            for (Foo foo : foos) {
                marshaller.marshal(foo, output);
            }
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("JAXB couldn't marshal. Handle it.", e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Task was interrupted. Handle it.", e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Task failed to execute. Handle it.", e);
        }
    }

    class DelayedFoos implements Callable<List<Foo>> {
        private int delaySeconds;

        public DelayedFoos(int delaySeconds) {
            this.delaySeconds = delaySeconds;
        }

        public List<Foo> call() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(delaySeconds * 1000);
            return Arrays.asList(new Foo(fooCounter++), new Foo(fooCounter++), new Foo(fooCounter++));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Starting Grizzly with the JAX-RS resource");
        final String baseUri = "http://localhost:9998/";
        final Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "rds.jersey");
        SelectorThread threadSelector = GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create(baseUri, initParams);
        System.out.println("Grizzly started");
        System.out.println("Starting a thread to request the streamed XML");
        executorService.submit(new HttpRequester(baseUri + "streaming"));
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
class Foo {
    @XmlElement
    private int id;

    Foo() {}

    public Foo(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

class HttpRequester implements Runnable {
    private String url;

    public HttpRequester(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Doing HTTP GET on " + url);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Client got: " + line);
            }
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Some bad I/O happened. Handle it.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Important points/differences to take note of:

1. Returning a Response from your resource method indicates that the entire response is contained in that object and doesn't allow for incremental updates to the response. Return a StreamingOutput instead. That tells Jersey that you'll be sending back a stream of data, which you can append to at will until you're done. The StreamingOutput gives you access to an OutputStream, which is what you use to send incremental updates and is the key to this whole thing. Of course, that means you have to handle the marshaling yourself. Jersey can only do the marshaling if you're returning the entire response at once.
2. Since the OutputStream is how you send back the data a little at a time, you either have to do the threading in your JAX-RS resource or pass the OutputStream down to your DriverController and write to it there.
3. Be sure to invoke flush() on the OutputStream if you want to force it to send out data immediately. Otherwise, nothing will be sent to the client until whatever internal buffer is filled up. Note that invoking flush() yourself circumvents the purpose of the buffer and makes your app more chatty.

All in all, to apply this to your project, the primary thing to do is change your resource method to return a StreamingOutput implementation and invoke your DriverController from inside that implementation, passing the OutputStream to the DriverController. Then in the DriverController, when you get some Articles back from a thread, instead of adding it to a queue for later, write it to the OutputStream immediately.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, can you help me apply this to my project?

Comment: @Jack: Added some notes to my answer. See if that helps you out.

Comment: Thanks a million for this stunningly comprehensive answer and for helping me out. This deserves recognition far beyond the 100 reputation I can give you by acceting this answer.

Comment: The writing to the OutputStream works. Unfortunately I have three issues I have to fix: 1) Chrome gives back: "This page contains the following errors: error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document", to me the XML tree looks normal though. 2) The output is not formatted, is there a way to tell the marshaller to format the XML? 3) As you have noticed I had a response Object that was marshalled wrapping the articles in a <response status="ok"><articles><article>...</article></articles></response>, how can I do that again and also write <?xml version="1.0" ... ?> in there?

Comment: Firefox says XML-Parsing-Error: "Junk" (translated into English) and displays a an ^ in the last line, is this a spacing problem?

Comment: @Jack: Unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience with using JAXB for partial XML. You might learn something from the [Marshaller javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#supportedProps) or some of the other JAXB docs. In particular, you'll be interested in the jaxb.formatted.output property for formatting. Keep in mind that you don't necessarily have to use JAXB for the output. Maybe another XML library would suit this problem better. When checking XML in a browser, you usually want to view source to be sure it really looks okay.

Answer (score 0):

@Ryan Stewart: how would we resolve same issue in axis2.x SOAP based web service kind of environment and HTML page as web client.
What I think is DriverController can keep Future objects in session and returns very first available response(article) with a unique session identifier to client....then client can make another webservice call (preferably thru Ajax+jquery) passing saved session identifier which would trigger DriverController to search more results and send back....is it a viable solution? Would it applicable for above environment too.